# How to print only last line in a while loop

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

```
count = 0

while count ** 2 < snum_:
    print "Using search with increment 1, the root lies between", count,"and", count + 1
    count = count + 1
```

How do I get the loop to only print the last possible line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
count = 0

while count < 4:
    print('hi')
    count += 1
else:
    # Replace below string with what you wish.
    print('end')
```

`+=` means `count + 1`. `else` is reached after `while` finishes (will not print, if you `break` the loop instead of letting it finish normally).

Answer (score 0):

You could save the string you want to print and print it **after** the loop:

```
count = 0
result = ''

while count ** 2 < snum_:
    result = "Using search with increment 1, the root lies between %d and %d" % count, count + 1
    count = count + 1

print result
```

Comment: Best not to use the name `str` for a variable since it masks the built-in function by the [same](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) name.

Comment: @Pyson good point - bad Java habits, I guess. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Two more points Java guy: 1) You do not need to set `result = ''` before the loop; 2) either use `"Using search with increment 1, the root lies between %d and %d" % (count, count + 1)` or, better still `"Using search with increment 1, the root lies between {} and {}".format(count, count + 1)`    ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With a for-loop and `itertools.count()`:

```
import itertools
for count in itertools.count(1):
    if count**2 >= snum_:
        print "Using search with increment 1, the root lies between %d and %d" % count-1, count
        break
```

But the general idea can also be applied to your while loop: When `count**2` is *no longer* less than `snum_`, print and break.